# Rails nested form with accepts_nested_attributes_for and belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm building a form in Rails (5.2.6) and I want to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, much like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34863818/rails-one-form-to-two-models). However, the answer on that question isn't working, and I suspect it's because my model already `belongs_to` another one.

**Background**
Essentially, I'm storing the results of AB tests. What I'm trying to achieve is the ability for Clients to have unique metrics that they track for their tests. The Metrics model allows users to identify the extra aspects to track while Outcomes is meant to store that data.

**What I've Tried**
I want to record the Outcomes at the same time that I record the Results; my approach has been to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :outcomes` on the Test model, but I keep getting the `Unpermitted parameter: :outcome` error.

Here are my models:

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :tests, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :metrics, dependent: :destroy
    validates :name, presence: true
end

class Metric < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :outcomes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tests, through: :outcomes

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :data_type, presence: true
end

class Test < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :results
  has_many :outcomes
  has_many :metrics, through: :outcomes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :outcomes, allow_destroy: true

  validates :name, presence: true
end

class Result < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :test
end

class Outcome < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :metric
  belongs_to :test

  validates :result, presence: true
end
```

and (some of) my controllers:

```
class TestsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
    @test = @client.tests.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
    @test = @client.tests.new
    @test.build_outcome
  end
  
  def create
    @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
    @test = @client.tests.create(test_params)
    redirect_to client_path(@client)
  end

  def edit
    @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
    @test = @client.tests.find(params[:id])
  end
  
  def update
    @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
    @test = @client.tests.find(params[:id])

    if @test.update(test_params)
      redirect_to client_test_path(@client, @test)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
    @test = @client.tests.find(params[:id])
    @test.destroy
    redirect_to client_path(@client)
  end
  
  
  private
    def test_params
      params.require(:test).permit(:name, outcome_attributes: [:result])
    end
end

class OutcomesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @test = Test.find(params[:test_id])
    @outcome = @test.outcome.find(params[:id])
  end
  
  def create
    @test = Test.find(params[:test_id])
    @outcome = @test.outcomes.create(outcome_params)
    redirect_to test_path(@test)
  end

  def edit
    @test = Test.find(params[:test_id])
    @outcome = @test.outcomes.find(params[:id])
  end
  
  def update
    @test = Test.find(params[:test_id])
    @outcome = @test.outcomes.find(params[:id])

    if @outcome.update(outcome_params)
      redirect_to test_outcome_path(@test, @outcome)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @test = test.find(params[:test_id])
    @outcome = @test.outcomes.find(params[:id])
    @outcome.destroy
    redirect_to test_path(@test)
  end
  
  
  private
    def outcome_params
      params.require(:outcome).permit(:test)
    end
end
```

And the form:

```
<%= form_with model: [ @test, @test.results.build ] do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :participants %><br>
    <%= form.number_field :participants %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :completed %><br>
    <%= form.number_field :completed %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :confidence %><br>
    <%= form.number_field :confidence %>
  </p>

  <% if @test.client.metrics.count > 0 %>
    <%= form.fields_for :outcome do |a| %>

      <% @test.client.metrics.each do |m| %>
        <p>
          <%= a.label m.name %><br>
          <%= a.number_field :result %>
        </p>
      <% end %>

      
    <% end %>
   <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its two simple pluralization errors.

```
params.require(:test)
      .permit(:name, outcomes_attributes: [:result])
```

[The param naming scheme for `has_many` is *plural*_attributes.](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::ClassMethods-label-One-to-many)

For `fields_for` you need to use the same name as the method on the object:

```
<%= form.fields_for :outcomes do |a| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

You're also using the wrong route if you want to submit a test with nested results:

```
<%= form_with model: @test do |form| %>
```

Do not use `.new` or its alias `.build` in the arguments to `form_with`. It prevents code reuse and will blank out any user input as you're always binding the form to a new record. Build/fetch records in the controller and pass them to the view.

And on a side note be careful with `<% if @test.client.metrics.count > 0 %>`. `count` always creates an additional database query. Use `#size` or `#any?` instead to avoid this.

Comment: In addition to these errors you have a lot of code duplication, redundant and broken code like OutcomesController#create and `validates :result, presence: true`. Its also very unclear why you have two classes with very semantically similiar names `Outcome` and `Result` which is bound to lead to confusion.

Comment: I updated it as you said, but I'm getting the same error. (Thanks for the `.count` explanation; I swapped that.) I agree that `Outcome` and `Result` are too similar, but this is a test app before I apply my solution to my actual project, so I wasn't overly concerned with their names.

Comment: I get the feeling that the stuff I have pointed out is really just the tip of the iceberg here. Create a simpler example and just figure out how nested attributes works first - its complicated enough anyways and this code looks like you're trying to do multiple layers of nesting which is pretty advanced stuff.